# Write to screen/console but not to .log file

Tags: tex-core, terminal-output, console

I use LaTeX without Lua extensions. Is there a platform-independent possibility built into (La)TeX for writing a message to screen only but **not** to the .log file?

Comment: I do not know if it exists ... and especially I do not see what it could serve.

Answer (score 7):

Without LuaTeX it's not possible. Internally TeX knows how to write to the terminal only, but it does not provide this option at the macro level.

A bit of context: TeX represents files using two arrays: *`write_file`*, a pointer to the output stream and *`write_open`*, a boolean which tells TeX whether the stream is connected or not to an actual file. The *`write_file`* array has 16 positions (0 . . 15) which point to each of the 16 possible open files (in LuaTeX they are 128), and the *`write_open`* array has two extra positions:

> [image: section §1370 of <code>tex.pdf</code>]

Now, when a `\write` is processed by TeX, what actually happens under the hood is the *`write_out`* procedure in §1370. The procedure starts by expanding the token list passed to `\write` (§1371) and then sets `j ⟵ write_stream(p)`, which holds the pointer to the 
write stream. The code then checks whether the given stream is open using `write_open[j]`. If that's the case, then the pointer to the write stream is assigned to *`selector`*, otherwise it checks the value of *`j`* to write either to *`term_and_log`* or to *`log_only`*; there's no option for *`term_only`*. Finally the writing and some bookkeeping is done. Here's the relevant section of `tex.pdf`:

> [image]

---

In very specific circumstances TeX writes something to the terminal which does not end up in the `.log`. From what I could find from the documentation, these cases are:

- when TeX starts in interactive mode (*i.e.,* you called just `tex` from the command line, without an input file), then its initialisation up to the `**` prompt are written to the terminal only. If you type a file name to the `**` prompt then the `.log` file name is derived from it, otherwise `texput` is used. In both cases, eventually what went to the terminal is also flushed to the `.log`;
- when showing boxes with `\tracingonline=0`; TeX will print the contents of the box to the `.log` only and will print `(see the transcript file)` to the terminal;
- when writing the final `Transcript written on <log-file>.log.`; and
- when some error/warning was issued and the interaction mode is either `\scrollmode` or `\nonstopmode`, then a `(see the transcript file for additional information)` is printed at the end of the run;

but none of these offer you an opportunity to write something yourself, so you're out of luck here.

Answer (score 2):

While this answer works, it is very hacky that it's only for "educational" purpose. Besides, it's not platform-independent and require `shell-escape`.

There's a quirk/feature in TeX live that if you open a file with name `|...` then TeX will spawn a process with command `...` and anything written to that "file" will be written to the process's stdin.

Side note, in certain situations (I haven't been able to track it down) `.tex` is appended to the command so `echo a` might become `echo a.tex`.

Anyway, the following LaTeX file

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {|cat}
\iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {hello~world}
\iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {hello~world}
\iow_now:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {hello~world}
\stop
```

will write the content to the terminal without writing it to the log file, assuming UNIX-like operating system with a command `cat`.