# Is it possible to read a line from the terminal without writing the content to the log file?

Tags: tex-core, logging

The question is in the title.

For example with the following file `a.tex`

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ior_str_get_term:nN {} \l_tmpa_tl
\stop
```

when compiled with `pdflatex a.tex`, and type something on the terminal, note that the same content is written on the log file.

Comment: No, basically everything goes to the log file ([lengthier explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508813/134574)).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This one is about `\read` instead of `\write` though?

Comment: Yes, but the observations at the end of that answer still apply (the part that starts with "In very specific circumstances...").  Roughly, the only thing that TeX doesn't write to the log is info telling you to look at the `.log` (e.g. `(see the transcript file)`), which would look silly so Don was careful not to write that to the log.  Everything else goes

Comment: I think using the pipe solution similar to that of my solution in the linked question also works. (expl3 has a proper wrapper for this one `sys_get_shell`) But I didn't test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If TeX knows it is the terminal it will echo it to the log.

But on systems that support named pipes you can do something. (Linux, or I am using cygwin on windows here)

set up the pipe

```
mkfifo my_pipe
```

Confirm it is there

```
file my_pipe 
my_pipe: fifo (named pipe)
```

Now get tex to read from that:

```
\openin2 my_pipe
\read2 to \xxx

\xxx

\bye
```

Running pdftex on the above it will hang waiting for input just as if you had used `\read-1` to read from stdin.

Now you can use in a second terminal

```
echo abc > my_pipe
```

At which point pdftex will complete the run typesetting `abc` to the pdf without writing it to the log.

Comment: that, however, is a feature of the hosting system, not of *TeX by itself, right?

Comment: @jarnosz well a combination of the two, the fact that tex does not log lines read from a pipe is  feature of tex. The fact that named pipes are available is an OS feature.